# element not updated when data changes

Tags: polymer-2.x, vaadin-elements

I have a `vaadin-checkbox`:

```
<vaadin-checkbox id=[[item.id]] disabled="true" checked="[[item.checked]]">[[item.description]]</vaadin-checkbox>
```

I defined my properties:

```
static get properties() {
    return {
        items: {
            type: Array,
            notify: true,
            value: function() {
                return [];
            }
        }
    };
}
```

When I now change the data by pressing some button:

```
_selectItem(event) {
    const item = event.model.item;

    if (item.checked === true) {
        this.$.grid.deselectItem(item);
    } else {
        this.$.grid.selectItem(item);
    }

    item.checked = !item.checked;
}
```

The state of the checkbox is still `checked="true"`. Why isnt the checkbox getting updated? The same thing when I change the description of the item:

```
_selectItem(event) {
    event.model.item.description = 'test';
}
```

The `test` description is never appearing. The checkbox is never getting updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the checkbox does not get updated by the button click handler is in the Polymer 2 data system. Polymer does not detect the change and does not update the template accordingly.

In order to make the change in a way that Polymer would detect it you have two options:

- Use `` this.set(`items.${event.model.index}.checked`, !item.checked) `` if you can reliably assume that the `index` used by `dom-repeat` always matches that elements's index in the `items` array (it is not the case if you use sorting or filtering features of `dom-repeat`). See an example here https://jsfiddle.net/vlukashov/epd0dn2j/
- If you do not know the index of the updated item in the `items` array, you can also use the [`Polymer.MutableData`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-system#mutable-data) mixin and notify Polymer that *something* has changed inside the `items` array without specifying the index of the changed item. This is done by calling `this.notifyPath('items')` after making a change. However, this requires that your element extends the `Polymer.MutableData` mixin, and that `dom-repeat` has the `mutable-data` attribute set. See an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/vlukashov/epd0dn2j/24/

More information on this in the [Polymer 2 docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-system#make-observable-changes).

Comment: thx for your answer but the examples arent working for me. maybe because my checkboxes are inside a vaadin-grid? I try setting up an example fiddle.

Comment: Could you please share more context? Where does the event handled by `_selectItem(event)` come from?

On another note, could you describe the use case you are implementing? If you need a checkbox to reflect the selection state of an item in a vaadin-grid, have you looked at the [`<vaadin-grid-selection-column>` element](https://vaadin.com/elements/vaadin-grid/html-examples/grid-selection-demos#grid-selection-demos-multi-selection-column)?

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong. Your solution with `this.set(\`items.${event.model.index}.checked\`, !item.checked)` works perfectly. Had another issue in my code. I need to have a seperate checkbox due to a very special design which is very hard to implement using the `<vaadin-grid-selection-column>`